# How can I use NiFi processor RouteOnContent

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to read a log file like that one:

```
199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985
199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085
burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0" 304 0
199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73-patch-small.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 4179
```

I'm sending 1000 lines each time I run this exercise, and I'm using a splitText processor, and in the extractText processor I use this regex:

```
successCode -> ^[0-9A-Z\-a-z\.]* - - \[[0-9A-Za-z\/\:]* -[0-9]*\] \"[A-Z]* [0-9A-Za-z\/\.\- ]*\" ([0-9]*) [0-9]*
tiemStamp -> ^[0-9A-Z\-a-z\.]* - - \[([0-9A-Za-z\/\:]*) -[0-9]*\] \"[A-Z]* [0-9A-Za-z\/\.\- ]*\" [0-9]* [0-9]*
important -> ^([0-9A-Z\-a-z\.]*) - - \[[0-9A-Za-z\/\:]* -[0-9]*\] \"[A-Z]* [0-9A-Za-z\/\.\- ]*\" [0-9]* [0-9]*
```

It can be a mistake on it. Surely here is my problem.

Then, I tryed to send different logs to different routes. If successCode == 200 then I tried to put it on route /user//success/%{tiemStamp}/, but all my lines go to the third way: "unmatched"

On the RouteOnContent processor I've tryed:

```
successCode -> ${successCode:equals("200")}
successCode -> ${successCode:contains(2)}
successCode -> ${successCode:contains("2")}
```

Has anyone worked with "RouteOnContent" processor?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, the `ExtractText` Processor "Evaluates one or more Regular Expressions against the content of a FlowFile. **The results of those Regular Expressions are assigned to FlowFile Attributes** [...]"

So you should not use a `RouteOnContent` but a `RouteOnAttribute` processor in the next step.

(If you stop your `RouteOnXXX` processor in order to keep the messages in the queue, you can see the content of the flowfiles. On the "Attributes" tab of a flowfile, you can see the values of the different attributes. And I confirm that with your regexp, I have successCode=200. )

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can use both `RouteOnAttribute` or `RouteOnText`, but each uses different parameters.

If you chose to use `ExtractText`, the properties you defined are populated for each row (after the original file was split by `SplitText` processor).
Now, you have two options:

1. Route based on the **attributes** that have been extracted (RouteOnAttribute).
2. Route based on the **content** (RouteOnContent). In this case, you don't really need to use `Extract Text`.

Each processor routes the FlowFile differently:

1. **RouteOnAttribute** queries the attributes of the FlowFile (a NiFi Expression Language query). For example, let's say I defined the property 'name', routing based on its value can be:
   [image]
2. On the other hand, **RouteOnContext** queries the content of the FlowFile based on a regex expression. For example:
   [image]

After defining these parameters, you can continue to route based on these dynamic relationships:
[image]